# Find a polynomial that generates Ideal

Tags: polynomials, ideals

Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ denote the ring of polynomials with real coefficients in $x$. I have already proved
that $$S=\{f \in \mathbb{R}[x] \mid f(2)=0\}$$
is an Ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$. The next step is to find a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, that generates $S$. I was thinking about the principal ideal $(x^2-4)$:

Clearly $(x^2-4) \subseteq S$, but I don't think that the other inclusion necessarily holds. Am I on the right path? Maybe there is an obvious answer to this?

Comment: $f(2) = 0$ is the same as $(x-2)$ dividing $f(x)$. Importantly, note that $x-2 \notin (x^2-4)$. Do you see the 'obvious' answer now?

Comment: @OsamaGhani You're right, this makes sense. That means that for every $f \in S$ there exists a $g \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ with $f=g(x-2)$, so $f \in (x-2)$. Thank you!

Comment: @SilverPine Last but not the least, see the generalizations : for example, if the ideal was $S' = \{f \in \mathbb R[x] : f(2) = f(-2) = 0\}$ then in fact the generator of the ideal is $(x-2)(x+2) = x^2-4$. So you are now familiar with finding generators of such ideals.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon this really makes sense, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!